# How to refer to a file with name beginning `--`?

Tags: linux, file-management

How can I rename or open or do anything with this file?

Everything I try (`rm`, `mv`, `cat`, `less`, `vi`) gives `unrecognised option '--.html'`

So far, only a full `ls` piped to `grep` has been useful, or even usable.

```
stewart$ ls -l | grep html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stewart stewart  18262 Mar 13 06:08 --.html
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Didn't know about the putting the lone `--` first to disable options.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I worked it out. This worked:

```
rm ./--.html
```

Comment: Many programs also understand a parameter `--`, which will stop them from interpreting further entries starting with `-` as options.